# Split php array to group when value is range or no

Tags: php, arrays

I have array value like this :

```
$src = array(3,15,16,17,18,20,25,7);
```

How can i split it into :

```
array(
    [0] => 3,
    [1] => array([0] => 15, [1] => 18),//when value is range get start and end
    [2] => 20,
    [3] => 25,
    [4] => 
 );
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. Could you please restate the question?

Comment: the question is unclear. Elaborate your issue

Comment: basically, what he is asking is ... if input is 1,2,3,4,5, he wants it to be `[0]=>1,[1]=>5`. My question is if you have a case where your sequence is `1,3,4,20` do you want to have it as `[0]=>3,[1]=>4` or just `3,4`?

Comment: @Dimi, he didn't say so

Comment: @Dimi correct.. when sequence is 1,3,4,20 i want to have it as [0]=>1,[1]=>array ([0] =>3,[1]=>4),[2]=>20

Comment: wich such random logic why one can't create another range like `array(
    [0] => 3,
    [1] => array([0] => 18, [1] => 20),//when value is range get start and end
    [2] => 25,
 );` ?

Comment: This would make a good code golf question...

Comment: @All, I am sorry. what should i write for the question title ? i just want to ask how to split array value to 2 group  : 1.single value 2.sequence / range value.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code. If your sequence/range difference is based on only next numbers, then this code would work for you.

```
<?php
$src = array(3,15,16,17,18,20,25,7);
$tot = count($src);
$resarr = array();
$st = $ed = '';
for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++){
    if($st==''){
        if(isset($src[$i+1]) && $src[$i+1] == $src[$i]+1){
            $st = $src[$i];
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!isset($src[$i+1]) || $src[$i+1] != $src[$i]+1){
            $ed=$src[$i];
        }
    }
    if($st=='' && $ed==''){
        $resarr[] =  $src[$i];
    }
    elseif($st!='' && $ed!=''){
        $resarr[] = array($st,$ed);
        $st = $ed='';
    }
 }
print_r($src);
echo "<pre>";print_r($resarr);echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Also phpfiddle example is here http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/k7c4-wvdg. Keep practice write your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Make copy of array with shifting to one item. 
// And, to save array length, add one element to the end of the array. 
// It can be any number, but not continue sequence. 
// I add the last item of source array
$src1 = $src;
array_shift($src1);
array_push($src1,end($src));

// Then subtract corresponding items of array
$temp = array_map(function ($i, $j) { return $j-$i; }, $src, $src1);
// Look at arrays 
// $src   3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20,  25, 7
// $temp 12,  1,  1,  1,  2,  5, -18, 0, 
// As you can see, all elements of sequences, but the last, has 1 in `temp` array.  
// Therefore, we just need to collect the result 
$sarr = false;
$result = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($src); $i++) {
  if($temp[$i] == 1) {
      if(! $sarr) {
        $sarr = $src[$i];
      }
  }
  else {
     if(! $sarr) {
       $result[] = $src[$i];
     }
     else {
       $result[] = [$sarr, $src[$i]];
       $sarr = false;
     }
  }        
}

print_r($result);
```

**[Test it there](https://eval.in/785708)**

Answer (score 0):

I added some values just to cover edge cases. Comments explain.

```
<?php
$src = array(3,4,15,16,17,18,20,25,7,8);

$res = [];
$start = null;

//Rather than make a counter use a for loop
for($i=0; $i < count($src); $i++){
    //Make sure i+1 is not bigger than array
    //If current index value + 1
    //Euqals the next index value we have a range
    if($i+1 < count($src) && $src[$i]+1 == $src[$i+1]){
        if($start === null){
            $start = $i;
        }
        //Once the range is over we can use the current index as end
    } elseif($start !== null){
        $res[] = array($src[$start], $src[$i]);
        $start = null;
        $end = null;
        //There was never a range.
    } else {
        $res[] = $src[$i];
    }
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 18
        )

    [2] => 20
    [3] => 25
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )

)
```